# Docker + Vitejs ENV variables without .env files

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, vite

I have an application With vue 3 + ViteJs. I'm trying to configure the env variables in docker compose but in vitejs configuration step the env vars was empty, I deduce that is not in running time and the vite config is in "build time".

Furthermore, I see an option with .env file (or .env.staging, or .env.production, ...) but I'm interested in another option more "dynamic", in docker, dev, stg, pro, ... I want different configurations.

The question is, anyone knows an alternative to .env files ?

Comment: I don't sure if your image has been prepared to receive an argument on build time. In a Dockerfile, you may be creating ARG or ENV to tell the container to use it. and passing the value on build time.
Can you tell me more about your Dockerfile?